# Installing Apache Mahout 0.11.0 on RHEL on multinode hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, mahout

**Need help on how to configure mahout to run on multinode hadoop cluster. Also how to run sample programs shipped with Mahout.**

Steps done till now:

1. Download tar gz file.
2. sudo tar -zxvf mahout-distribution-x.x.tar.gz.
3. sudo mv mahout-distribution-x.x /usr/lib/mahout
4. sudo gedit ~/.bashrc".
5. export MAHOUT_HOME=/usr/local/mahout
6. source ~/.bashrc".

Comment: This is enough. Mahout is not a running service. Now you can submit mahout jobs

Comment: @Amal Facing an issue while submitting mahout job

1) Downloaded and unzippped ml-100k.zip and put on hdfs u.data file
2) set java, hadoop home. Using hadoop 2.6 on 3 node cluster
3) mahout recommenditembased -s SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE –i /mahout/examples/input/u.data –o /mahout/examples/output
4) Also tried --input and --output

Getting below error
Running on hadoop, using /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop

**ERROR AbstractJob: Unexpected –i while processing Job-Specific Options:
Unexpected –i while processing Job-Specific Options:**

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:$MAHOUT_HOME/bin
```